# How to toggle 'add' in "element.classList.add" to remove using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, function, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am trying to use a single function to add and remove a class using javascript. Instead of having two almost identical functions, i've tried to create one that takes an action as an argument (add or remove) to add/ remove a class from an element.

When I pass in the argument, js seems to not recognize it.

This is what I am currently working with:

```
// function that adds or removes a class
const animateHomeBtn = (axn) => {
    arrowEl.classList.axn('arrow-hover')
    btnTextEl.classList.axn('btn-text-hover')
}

// event listener to add a class when mouse hovers an element
    heroBtn.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => animateHomeBtn(add))
})

// event listener to remove a class when mouse move out of element
    heroBtn.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => animateHomeBtn(remove))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this:

1. Pass string in `animateHomeBtn` function like:

   ```
   heroBtn.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => animateHomeBtn('add'))
   heroBtn.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => animateHomeBtn('remove'))
   ```
2. Then update `animateHomeBtn` function like:

   ```
   const animateHomeBtn = (axn) => {
      arrowEl.classList[axn]('arrow-hover')
      btnTextEl.classList[axn]('btn-text-hover')
   }
   ```

or, you can simply use [`.toggle(className)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) like:

```
heroBtn.addEventListener('mouseenter', animateHomeBtn)
heroBtn.addEventListener('mouseleave', animateHomeBtn)

const animateHomeBtn = () => {
   arrowEl.classList.toggle('arrow-hover')
   btnTextEl.classList.toggle('btn-text-hover')
}
```

- The `.toggle()` method is used to toggle between adding and removing a class name from an element with JavaScript.

Comment: the .toggle() definitely makes this easier! I had some trouble getting the toggle to work. It would skip every other mouseenter or mouseleave. Thanks for clearing this up!